# Legendre–Fenchel Convex Conjugate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

What is the easiest way to compute the convex conjugagte of a real convex function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f^*(s) = \sup_{x} \{ s x - f(x) \}$

I know I can compute the derivative of the inner objective function w.r.t $x$, solve the equation comparing the derivative to 0, and substitute the result into the objective to discover $f^*$. However, is there a built-in function, or an easy one-liner to do that?

Comment: `fc[s_] := MaxValue[s x - f[x], x]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2, actually, it does not work for  very simple cases, i.e. `MaValue[s x - Log[1+E^x], x]` says that no global maxima found (although clearly the function is strictly concave and the unique critical point is a global maximum).

Comment: @AlexShtoff Michael is [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaBBZ.png)